# Can I run/build Malzilla on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, build

I'd like to use Malzilla on Mac OS X but I can;t find any binaries. Would it be easy to build it for Mac OS X?

Comment: What do you think the point of looking for Windows malware on a Mac would be exactly?

Comment: For the uninitiated (like me), MalZilla itself is not malware, but an anti-malware tool. The previous comment confused me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

[Malzilla](http://malzilla.sourceforge.net/) is Windows only.

An alternative way of having it, is using [Wine](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/) (some people on internet successfully did it).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Studer, Malzilla only has Windows binaries available.

You could have a look at [Sophos](http://www.sophos.com/products/free-tools/free-mac-anti-virus/); it is a free antimalware program for Mac.